# CSS3 hiding transition

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a menu where the height and visibility transitions on hover, and transitions back when it's not hovered. It works fine, but the links collapse on top of each other when it's fading back to hidden. I've been searching everywhere and I can't figure out how to keep them from collapsing on top of each other. So my question is, how do I stop it from doing that? Is it just some simple solution that I'm overlooking, or is it something more complex?

HTML

```
<header>
<section id="logo_section">
    <h1><a href="#">FLASH OF REALITY</a></h1>
    <p>Photography, Film, & Animation in Utah</p>
</section>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Video</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Animation</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">My Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Service</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    /ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

CSS

```
header ul li {
visibility: hidden;
height: 0px;
transition: visibility .5s, height .5s;
}

header:hover ul li {
visibility: visible;
height: 57px;
}
```

Comment: What do you want it to do instead? It looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/sfLCm/ .. also, note: You have a syntax error. Look at the `</ul>` close tag.

Comment: You see how the list elements all start collapsing at the same time? I would like the last one to collapse first, then when that one is finished the next one would collapse and so on.

Comment: I mimic your code and I notice it does work if you close the </ul> like this

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more specific. I edited my first comment so it's more clear.

Comment: did you close the div <ul> div and try to see if that works for you?

Comment: Yes, the unclosed </ul> was just a miss-copy on the copy/paste. The transitioning works, but instead of all the <li> tags collapsing at the same time I would like them to collapse in order from last to first with their <a> tags disappearing as they collapse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you transition the height of the `<li>` items, they will each gradually go to 0, so they'll all just be sitting on top of each other as they have no height.

[image]

Instead of transitioning the `<li>`, you could transition a max-height of the `<ul>` from 0 to a value that is taller than the list will be.

```
header ul {
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .5s;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header:hover ul {
  max-height: 600px;
}
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/4CfeU/2/**

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks man. I don't know why I didn't think of that. It seems so obvious after looking at it.

Comment: No problem.  Note that the transition speeds can be a bit odd from hover on to hover off, because of the max-height.